# How to create a composable where with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

My code:

```
defmodule Model1 do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "model1" do
    belongs_to :model2, Model2
  end

  def create_query do
    Model1
    |> join(:inner, [m1], m2 in assoc(m1, :model2))
  end

  def apply_where(query, %{name: name})  do
    query
    |> where([m1, m2], ilike(m2.name, ^name))
  end
end


defmodule Model2 do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "model2" do
    has_many :model1, Model1
    field :name, :string
  end
end
```

When I try:

```
param = %{name: "test"}
Model1.create_query |> Model1.apply_where(param) |> Repo.all
```

It's work fine. But, is there any way to code apply_query function like this:

```
def apply_where(query, %{name: name})  do
  query
  |> where([m2], ilike(m2.name, ^name))
end
```

And if my query has many join clauses? Will I have to declare all joined schemas (tables) in list (first where arg) [m1, m2, m3, ... mx] to bind a field every time?

Answer (score 0):

Because m2 is a binding in a join, you do have to specify `[m1, m2]`. This is dependent on position, not name, so your `apply_where` can have `[model_1, model_2]` and ecto would still understand what you meant even though the binding uses different names.

According to [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.5/Ecto.Query.html#content):

```
Bindings in Ecto are positional, and the names do not have to be consistent between 
input and refinement queries.
...
When composing queries you must specify bindings again for each refinement query.
```

However, in cases where you have many joins:

```
You are not required to specify all bindings when composing.
```

And in compositions where you're not worried about the joins:

```
Although bindings are extremely useful when working with joins, they are not
necessary when the query has only the from clause.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Cody Poll!
In my case, I use the query for two moments:
1 - search data with specific filters (where clause)
2 - search data to populate three combobox filters in screen using a distinct in column and no filter in where clause. I am trying to use the same query: For combobox I use Ecto.Query.exclude function to remove select, order-by and preload.
If joins are edited, I have impact in all my "apply_where" function. Composable queries are not useful because binding are positional and never are named when it's in differents scopes (separated functions).